# How to reset, from another Windows, the Safe/Diagnostic boot parameter set in MSCONFIG?

Tags: windows, boot, diagnostic, msconfig

My Win11 has worked perfectly.
I only wanted to see if an issue I had with another program might be due to installed programs.
The problem is that now, Win11 logon after boot, can't turn on the camera and can't find my Pin.
I am stuck in a loop.
I can reboot into a previous Win10 on a separate drive and it sees the camera OK.
Can I somehow, from Win10, using Regedit or something else, uncheck the Safe/Diagnostic boot parameter to be back to my normal, working Win11?
Edit:
I found this in the Win11 Registry (using Regedit from Win10):
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\MSConfig
NoRebootUI REG_DWORD 0x0000000
But, according something I've read, there should be sub-folders under the above key if MSConfig has set them - I have nothing under this key.

Comment: Try booting Windows to Safe Mode.  While running in this loop, try to restart it while running. You should be able to get into Safe Mode either from a screen dialogue or repeatedly pressing F8.  You need to check your documentation.

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess I should have said "dead-end" instead of "loop".
What I meant was, being forever in Safe mode logon, with Win11 telling me 'no camera' and 'can't find my pin' whenever I now boot into Win11.
Because I set safe-mode boot via msconfig, I now need to find how to unset it, but I can only do that using a Win10 logon and either regedit or some other tool...